# UItextfield to appear on touching (uitextview word)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uitextview, uigesturerecognizer

I am working on an app that has an uitextfield with some wrong content now user touches the wrong word , a new text field appear on that part , user enters the correct word and then submit.

I have succeed in fetching the correct word on touching the texview but have no idea how to deal with textfield.

Please suggest a good solution for this !

[image]

Comment: As u get the correct word then at that point u could add textField inside the textview with location of correct word or u could simply show textField below check button.

Comment: Please provide more information about what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to look at the UITextFieldDelegate Methods in this case. You can search SO for samples but check out the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/index.html) to get the big picture. Basically, you'll want to intercept the messages to verify that the user entered the correct text and then do something with the information provided by the user. Including things like dismiss the keyboard, add result to a score or do something else with the data (per your app design).